# Create Notation for a Fortran Kind constants?

Tags: types, fortran, notation

Can I create my own notation in Fortran for the kind of variables I am working on. If I am working on Fortran REAL variables of KIND 32, Can I create notation for it like "D" for Double, and "Q" for Quad while declaring constants of that KIND. Can I create variables with my own Alphabet say "U" while declaring constants of my Kind.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you are trying to ask. Some example syntax (even if you know it's not correct) might help.

Comment: If we declare real variable of kind 8 with some constant(say one) then we use: 'var = 1.D0' . Here 'D' is used to declare double variables with double constants. If I am working on variables of kind 32, i want to declare constant(one) with some  alphabet, like 'var = 1.U0'. Is it possible?

Comment: See Vladimir's answer then. Also note real( 8 ) is not portable, it is not guaranteed to do what you expect, and is not even guaranteed to be supported by your compiler. Use the constants in iso_fortran_env and the method outlined in Vladimir's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran uses suffixes for the kind of numerical (and some other) literals

```
1_int32  
4.2e5_real64
```

where `int32` and `real64` are the kind constants.

You cannot redefine the letter used for exponentiation. It is either E or D (for douple precision). Q is nonstandard.

Comment: Doesn't the question ask about _variables_ not _constants_?

Comment: @francescalus It does but there is often inconsistency in nomenclature in beginners' questions. I assume they want to define the value of some variable with such a constant. It is often better to wait for clarification but I am fairly sure here. If not, I will delete.

Comment: I thought it was either this or some horrible (ab-)use of Implicit. Hence asking for examples.